# searching an array with boolean

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

really stuck on this so any help appreciated i am just a beginner basically i have 3 classes called Account, Address & AccountCollection within the AccountCollection i have got to create a boolean search which will print a single account given a account number utilising a method of the Account class.  If this is invalid it should output "Account with account number: [ accountNumber] not found."

the code i have so far is

```
public boolean getAccount(String accountNumber)
{
    for (Account account : accounts)
    {
        if (account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))
        {
            account.printAccountDetails();
            System.out.println();
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;

}
```

which seems to work until i put in a wrong value then it gives me a null pointer exception 61 any help would be brilliant thanks

Comment: It means that an object in line 61 is `null`. Have a look at the line and check why each of them would be `null`. Without context, it is impossible for anyone else to find out.

Comment: Account number probably returns `int` *(or so I would presume)* - If so then you should be comparing via `==` and not `.equals()`.

However you are receiving an `NPE` in line 61 so you have to show us that line for us to understand what is going on.

Comment: hi the account number is a string and the line 61 is the one above as below                                                                if (account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array list and similar structures accepts adding null objects.

```
    ArrayList<String> asd = new ArrayList<>();
    asd.add(null);
    asd.get(0).substring(0); // it will crash here on calling substring() for null object.
```

You must check where you are adding a null account. and fix it there unless it's a requirement to accept a null object.

If you accept null objects for account do the following in your search method to skip null objects to the next ones.

```
public boolean getAccount(String accountNumber)
{
    for (Account account : accounts)
    {
        if(account != null)
        {
            if (account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))
            {
                account.printAccountDetails();
                System.out.println();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
public boolean getAccount(String accountNumber)
{
    for (Account account : accounts)
    {
        if(account == null) {
            return false;
        }  
        if (account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))
        {
            account.printAccountDetails();
            System.out.println();
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: he may have a null account in the middle of the list. your solution won't search for the accounts after the null account.